# Python for loop not working on custom container

Tags: python

**EDIT**: I added `__iter__` to my Map class (i forgot it didn't inherit from Tree), but now the for loop returns "generator objects":

```
<generator object _next at 0x82a4b94>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Map.py", line 43, in <module>
    print "First: %s, Second: %s" % (pair.first(), pair.second())
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'first'
```

So there's an issue with my next function, right?

---

For fun I created a RedBlack Tree in Python, and it's working properly. Now to copy the STL from C++ I'm creating a Map class to wrap the tree, for an alternative to the Python dict.

The issue is when I try and loop through the Map, it's not working properly.

```
phonebook = Map()
phonebook["Joe"] = "555-555-3422"
phonebook["Rob"] = "231-523-2357"

for pair in phonebook:
    print "First: %s, Second: %s" % (pair.first(), pair.second())
```

The error that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Map.py", line 38, in <module>
    for pair in phonebook:
  File "Map.py", line 19, in __getitem__
    return self._tree.find(key)
  File "Python/Tree/SearchTree.py", line 82, in find
    raise TreeException('No node with key %s' % key)
Tree.TreeException: 'No node with key 0'
```

I don't know why it's looking for key 0, when my keys are Strings.
Using pdb I noticed that after the for loop starts, the first line executed is a call to `__getitem__` with key 0....

Map is defined as:

```
class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        self._tree = RedBlackTree()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._tree.find(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self._tree.insert(Pair(key, item))
```

From my understanding, I had to create an iterator for my tree, for this to work properly. I wasn't quite sure how to do this, so I looked around and combined a few approaches:
(In my RedBlack tree implementation, NULL is an actual node)

```
class TreeIterator():
    def __init__(self, root, size):
        self._current = root
        self._size = size
        self.num_visited = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self._next(self._current)

    def _next(self, curr):
        self.num_visited = self.num_visited + 1
        if self.num_visited == self._size:
            raise StopIteration

        if curr.left is not None and curr.left is not TreeNode.NULL:
            for node in _next(curr.left):
                yield node

        yield curr
        if curr.right is not None and curr.right is not TreeNode.NULL:
            for node in _next(curr.right):
                yield node
```

and in my SearchTree superclass:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return TreeIterator(self.root, self.size)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"%s" % 0 == "%s" % "0"`. Use `repr` to see if it's a string, an int, or something completely different.

Comment: This isn't about your question per se, but I find the way `TreeIterator` iterates using `self._size` and `self.num_visited` to know when to stop a very strange way to limit the recursion -- something like that shouldn't be necessary for a correctly constructed tree data structure.

Comment: I wasn't originally doing that but I didn't know when to raise StopIteration. The recursion should stop properly but next will keep getting called...

Comment: `_next()` is a generator and will automatically raise a `StopIteration` when it falls off the end (which implicitly does a `return None` that is intercepted by the wrapper Python generates for functions it detects are generators -- i.e. those that have one or more `yield` statements in them).

Comment: Regardung your latest update: Does your new Map class `__iter__()` method return a `TreeIterator` instance? It should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Map class have not `__iter__` method, so `for` calls `__getitem__` instead. You should inherit Map from SearchTree or implement `__iter__` in Map.

Comment: When `for` calls `__getitem__` it passes integer indexes as keys.

Comment: Oh right! I was originally going to have Map inherit from RedBlack Tree, but instead it contains one..

Comment: About your update - in next function don't yield, just return. Or if you want yields - do it in `__iter__` function.

Comment: I tried that but then I can't do `for node in _next(curr.left): `

Comment: Try this `
    def __iter__(self):
        return self._next(self._current)`

Comment: That doesn't work either as I need the next() function implemented to be an iterator. Maybe put the whole iterator class in a new answer?

Comment: Now i'm going to sleep. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in order to use the map as an iterator in the conditional, the Map class has to implement next and iter. Am I mistaken in this?

Basically you'd be adding an `__iter__()` and next() method to the Map class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an object iterable, so that you can loop over it with a `for` loop, you have to implement `__iter__()` and `next()` (explained [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)).

When you loop over an object which has those two methods, Python calls `__iter__()` on the object first.  This method returns an object which has the `next()` method.  Then Python calls `next()` over and over, getting the items in the object one by one, until `next()` raises a `StopIteration` error.

There are two easy ways to get your code to work.  The first way is to just implement `__iter__()` and `next()` methods on your Map which call the equivalents on `self._tree`, and the second is to have your Map inherit from your tree class, and you get the iteration with no extra work.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to implement both -- you need to implement `__iter__`, and it needs to return an object that implements `next` -- it doesn't have to be your object, it could be a generator expression, `iter` on a callable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
class xxx (object) :
    def __init__ (self) :
        self._values = [1, 2, 3]

    def __iter__ (self) :
        return self._next ()

    def _next (self) :
       for v in self._values :
            yield v

       raise StopIteration

x = xxx ()
for _ in x : print _
```

Comment: Again this is returning a generator object instead of the Pair object I'm expecting it to return

Answer (score 0):

`next()` is a supposed to be a regular function, not a generator. `return` from it, don't `yield`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, unless you mean `_next()` should return, but then I can't do `for node in _next(cur.left)`